# Catalogues on github and my computer differ. How to make exact copy of catalogues on computer to github?

Tags: github

I have been commiting to github. Now there is quite a mess on github. So I removed, moved and added some files on my computer, commited all and pushed, but there are still old unnecesary files on github. How to add exact copy of my catalogue on computer to github, so that others can see it ?

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was to remove files from github, which were deleted on computer, but were tracked in git as `deleted: some_file`.

Following procedure worked for me:

`git add -u`

`commit -m "removed files manually."`

`git push`